# Property 'requestOptions' does not exist on type

Tags: angularjs, angular, http, post

I want to send data to WebAPI service from Angular web client .In this post method i m getting  an  compile error .'[ts] Property 'requestOptions' does not exist on type 'UserService'(Current Typescrpipt) .

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http,Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx'; ///Allow clients to subscribbe responces asnc and add Rx when handling errors catch block
import {User} from './user';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';


@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  constructor( private http : Http) { 

  }


  RegisterUser(user :User) {

    const headerDict = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
      }

      const requestOptions = {                                                                                                                                                                                 
        headers: new HttpHeaders(headerDict), 
      };

      const data = JSON.stringify(User);
      return this.http.post("http://localhost:53269/Api/RegisterUser", data, this.requestOptions );

      }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `HttpClientModule` with its `HttpClient` abstraction. Also you don't need to use `JSON.stringify` - it is extra

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {

   constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

   RegisterUser(user: User) {

      const headerDict = {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
      };

      const requestOptions = {                                                                                                                                                                                 
          headers: new HttpHeaders(headerDict), 
      };

      return this.httpClient.post("http://localhost:53269/Api/RegisterUser", user, requestOptions);   
  }    

}
```

One note. Not related to the actual issue. Don't import anything from `rxjs/Rx`. This will make your bundle huge. If you want to import `Observable` - just import like

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
```

If you want some operator - import it separately from `rxjs/operators` or `rxjs/observables/`

Use eihter `HttpClientModule` with `HttpClient` or `HttpModule` with `Http` - which is deprecated now

Comment: @charitht99perera if you use `HttpClient` instead of `Http`, your code will work. You need to just remove the `this` part from the `requestOptions`. I have updated answre

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
  const headersOption = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type')

  const data = JSON.stringify(User);
  return this.http.post("http://localhost:53269/Api/RegisterUser", data, {headers:headersOption});
```